# How to use Angular's safety-worker.js to uninstall Service Worker?

Tags: angular, progressive-web-apps, angular-service-worker

There are many step-by-step guides on using `ngsw-worker.js` to install ServiceWorker; yet there is not even one step-by-step guide on using `safety-worker.js` to uninstall ServiceWorker.

safety-worker.js is mentioned in https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-devops#safety-worker

**How do I use safety-worker.js to uninstall service worker? I want to uninstall a previously installed ngsw-worker.js.**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You just have to rename `safety-worker.js` to `ngsw-worker.js` on the production and keep it there for a while (say, until the majority of the app users get this update)

Comment: Is there a way to do this using Angular CLI when packaging the Angular app?

Comment: I'm not aware of any flag in Angular CLI for doing this file manipulation but I think it's better to have it on different level anyway. I suggest you to have "in reserve" a respective line in `scripts` of your `package.json` with the command that does this file operation. And "in case of emergency", you add this command (as the last one) to the main build command you have.

Answer (score 2):

according to an Angular official document if service-worker not found "ngsw.json" at server then it will uninstall service worker itself and clear browser cache storage itself.

I did implement in my project and do it practically not only theatrically.

just it is very simple you need to rename or delete ngsw.json file.

offical more info :https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-devops#fail-safe

Comment: Awesome. Saved me effort! Where did you see this instruction in the official document?

Comment: here is official link https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-devops#fail-safe

Answer (score 2):

I just had the same problem and I succesfully removed the service worker renaming the reference to the file `ngsw-worker.js` to `safe-worker.js` (I only had one reference in the `app.module.ts` file. The removing ngsw.json file solution did not work for me but the renaming solution worked.